# How do I use Buttons when I'm using unity's Enhanced Touch for a player controller that covers the whole screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a pause button on my game, and I have an EnhancedTouch based Player controller where I spawn a Joystick wherever I touch, the thing is I want to check if I'm pressing an unity UI element like a button/slider/dropdown, etc so it doesn't take into account that input specially buttons.

Is there a way of doing that or an alternative workaround? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Canvas game object, create a Panel that will be the area in with the floating joystick can be spawn. Bellow the Panel add your Button. Now create a global `TouchInputManager` component/script which will detect which UI element has been touched by performing a raycast when the user touches the screen. You can attach it to your Canvas GO.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;
using ETouch = UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;

public class TouchInputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GraphicRaycaster graphicRaycaster;
    private PointerEventData pointerEvtData = new(null);
    private List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new();

    private void Awake()
    {
        graphicRaycaster = GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    }

    private void HandleFingerDown(Finger finger)
    {
        pointerEvtData.position = finger.screenPosition;
        raycastResults.Clear();

        // Perform a raycast to find the UI element touched by the finger
        graphicRaycaster.Raycast(pointerEvtData, raycastResults);

        if (raycastResults.Count > 0)
        {
            var gameObj = raycastResults[0].gameObject;

            // Notify the UI element about the touch
            gameObj.SendMessage("OnFingerDown", finger, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Enable();
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerDown += HandleFingerDown;
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerUp += HandleFingerUp;
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerMove += HandleFingerMove;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Disable();
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerDown -= HandleFingerDown;
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerUp -= HandleFingerUp;
        ETouch.Touch.onFingerMove -= HandleFingerMove;
    }

    // Other methods ... //
}
```

If you're using the new `EnhancedTouch` API, you need to perform a raycast by yourself (from one global component/script) to check which UI element has been touched, or you could take a silly approach and register a touch handler on every UI element that checks if the specific UI element has been touched.

We're using `GraphicRaycaster` since it registers hits with game objects that have a `Graphic` component (i.e. UI elements).